# Server-side processing DataTables in Laravel Vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm new in Laravel and vuejs and I've been giving task which read the data from database and display it into DataTables but the pattern of the DataTables should server side processing, which means the `tbody data` should rendered only at the `vuejs` the tbody data should not display on the actual `table` just only `thead`, Currently I've been managed just to read all the data from database but the problem is the format of my DataTable is not server-side processing and it's need to be a custom way like the reference below. Is there anyway to convert this into server-side-processing?.  It would be great if anybody could figure out, thank you so much in advance!.

*Reference-Link server-side Processing*
[link](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side)

Current table
[Display image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk37Q.png)

*Table*

```
     <table class="table table-separate table-head-custom table-checkable" id="transaction-logs">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>Page</th>
                <th>Url</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Created</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for = "(transactionlogs, logs) in transactionlogs" :key="logs">
                <td>{{ logs+1}}</td>
                <td>{{transactionlogs.page}}</td>
                <td>{{transactionlogs.url}}</td>
                <td>{{transactionlogs.action}}</td>
                <td>{{transactionlogs.created_at}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

> Script

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            transactionlogs:{}
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.ini();
        this.getTransactionLogs();
    },
    methods:{
        getTransactionLogs(){
            axios.get('list_transaction_logs').then((response)=>{
                this.transactionlogs = response.data
            }).catch((errors)=>{
                console.log(errors)
            });
        },
        ini(){
            $(()=>{
                this.tdatatable().init();
            });
        },
        tdatatable(){
            var initTable = ()=> {
            var table = $('#transaction-logs');
            // begin first table
                table.DataTable({
                    scrollY: '50vh',
                    scrollX: true,
                    scrollCollapse: true,
                    processing: true,
                    columnDefs: [],
                });
            };
            return {
                init: function() {
                    initTable();
                },
            };
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: use https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net this as vue side and https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables as backend side no need to work any custom thing

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul thanks for your response but the requirements should be custom thing, but don't really know the format

Comment: `DataTables` is not custom and i mention `DataTables` for vue js

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul can you help me It's been 3 days now I've been searching

Comment: @Macy just go through doc and make it you can check there examples as well https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net/tree/master/example

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul Thanks for your response but I tried I honestly I didn't understand ,how can I implement this through that project :(